# Unable to Save to Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am saving a Django model and everything works except for one column in the model and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. I imagine just a fresh pair of eyes will see the likely basic error I am making. Here is an abbreviated snippet of my code:

My model:

```
class Commission(models.Model):
  base_product              = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, related_name='commissions',on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  requirement_images        = models.ManyToManyField(RequirementImageData)
  notes                     = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  artisan_notes             = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  admin_notes               = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  commission_log            = models.ManyToManyField(CommissionLogs)

  # DETAILS
  seller_id                 = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  quantity                  = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
  length                    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  width                     = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  height                    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  original_length          = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  original_width           = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  original_height          = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  estimated_artisan_price   = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  anou_fee                  = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) 
  estimated_weight          = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) 
  percent_difference        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=8,null=True, blank=True)
  requester_country         = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True, blank=True)
  country_code              = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True, blank=True)
  shipping_type             = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True, blank=True)
  estimated_shipping_price  = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) 
  total_price_mad           = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  adj_exchange_rate         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=8,null=True, blank=True)
  base_currency             = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  credit_card_fee           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2,null=True, blank=True)
  currency_symbol           = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True, blank=True)
  price_adjustment          = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

  # MILESTONES
  created_at                = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
  artisan_notified_at       = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  artisan_confirmed_at      = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  invoice_sent_at           = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  invoice_paid_at           = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  invoice_id                = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
  invoice_amount            = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True, blank=True)
  progress_updated_at       = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  progress                  = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
  complete_at               = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  admin_confirmed_at        = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  customer_confirmed_at     = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  something_wrong           = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  new_product_id            = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  new_product_image         = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
  completed_at              = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  sold_at                   = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  shipped_at                = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  canceled_at               = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

  # UPDATE HISTORY
  created_at                = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
  updated_at                = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
  progress_photos           = models.ManyToManyField(ProgressPhotos)
  status                    = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True, blank=True)
  first_deadline            = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  adjusted_deadline         = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  est_days_til_complete     = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  days_remaining            = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  checkout_id               = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True, blank=True)
```

My function:

```
def custom_order(custom_order_manager_data):
   from apps.commission.models.commission import Commission

   custom_order_id = custom_order_manager_data['customOrderId']
   custom_order_data = Commission.objects.get(id=custom_order_id)

   custom_order_data.checkout_id = checkout.id #checkout works ignore this
   print("CHECKOUT ID: ",checkout.id)
   print("CUSTOM ORDER CHECKOUT Public ID: ",custom_order_data.checkout_id)
   custom_order_data.save()
   print("Post Save ",custom_order_data.checkout_id)
```

When I check my logs, everything works and is printing the correct data, but it still isn't saving. Here are the logs:

```
CHECKOUT ID:  3380
CUSTOM ORDER CHECKOUT Public ID:  3380
Post Save  3380
```

For me this shows that the instance is gathering the correct data and it is saved correct to that instance, but it won't save in the db (all other data does though, it's just specifically when I'm trying to save to `checkout_id` that isn't working. I am getting no errors.

Here is what I've tried:

- I've changed the model name.
- I've changed the column name to something more unique.
- I've increased the `max_length` (from ten to twenty)
- I've tried saving data to `checkout_id` as an explicit string.

With something so basic, I assume it is something I'm overlooking. Can any one spot what my error is? Thank you!

Comment: I think there are other fields in your `Commission` model. If yes, please add them in your question body.

Comment: Sure, will update. Rather large, sorry.

Comment: Can you override the `save` method in `Commission` and print out its `kwargs` too? [Overriding save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

Comment: I will look into this and let you know.